# Very weird "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value" - error only on UPDATE

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
SELECT IF(TRUE, 'a', 'b') IS NOT NULL;
```

The following **fails** with error:

> Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'a':

```
CREATE TABLE tmp(col1 CHAR(10));
UPDATE tmp SET col1 = col1 WHERE IF(TRUE, 'a', 'b') IS NOT NULL;
```

Why?

Also, when doing `IS NULL` instead of `IS NOT NULL` - it works. i.e., this **works**:

```
UPDATE tmp SET col1 = col1 WHERE IF(TRUE, 'a', 'b') IS NULL;
```

Also, when running a `SELECT` query, it also **works**:

```
SELECT IF(TRUE, 'a', 'b') IS NOT NULL;
```

It seems like the issue is only with `UPDATE`, and only with `NOT NULL`.

How come?

**UPDATE**: this might be a new issue in MySQL 5.7. I tested on MySQL 5.5 and it worked, but did report the same issue as a warning:
[image: MySQL 5.5]

Comment: I think something else is going on - I cannot seem to reproduce it. Can you make a http://sqlfiddle.com to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I think it only started in MySQL 5.7. I just tried on an older version (5.5) and it worked... which MySQL version did you try with?

Comment: Fiddle is running 5.6, so that might be it.

Comment: This is a little of a guess as I'm by no means a mysql expert - but I think the issue is down to the when the `IS NOT NULL` check vs. the `IF()` results data type is parsed for execution in the update statement. The following works for example: `UPDATE tmp SET col1 = col1 WHERE IF(TRUE, 1, 'b') IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen thanks, it does seem like it has to do with the value that is returned from the IF(), but it still looks like a bug. Why does it happen only with `IS NOT NULL` and not with `IS NULL`? Why doesn't it happen when using `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE`? If there is an issue converting "a" to NULL, then how come this works: `UPDATE tmp SET col1 = col1 WHERE 'a' IS NOT NULL;` ?

Comment: I wish I had the concrete answer, but it could look like a bug yes. - my guess would be that the `'a' IS NOT NULL` works because the datatype is known at parsing time instead of at execution from the IF(). Why `IS NULL` works though, is a bit more mysterious :)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen yeah... well thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Indeed, it seems a bug in MySQL 5.7. Try changing the statement to something like: `UPDATE tmp SET col1 = col1 WHERE IF(TRUE, COALESCE('a'), COALESCE('b')) IS NOT NULL;`, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vgoufVyUBhzvtaCJ2cXQeJ/0).

Comment: @wchiquito (1) nice, it works! if you submit it as an answer, I will accept. (2) how did you think of or come across this solution? (3) do you have a reference for a documented bug for this?

Comment: See [Bug #43437](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43437) and [Bug #76353](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76353).